# TestNG how to iterate through different excel sheets from a source sheet

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Hello Experts: I am using Selenium Webdriver and TestNG. My datasource is an excel workbook that has multiple test data sheets. The workbook also has a summary sheet having the SheetNames of each test data sheet.

Using TestNG, is there a way to use take the SheetName from the summary sheet and work through each test data sheet in the workbook?

Eg:

- from summary sheet, Pick first sheetName (say sheet1)
- run all the testData in sheet1
- from summary sheet, Pick next sheetName (say sheet2)
- run all the testData in sheet2
- etc etc till the last sheetname in Summary sheet

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres my first solution that uses the factory to go through my summary sheet instantiating classes to parse through test records in each corresponding worksheet. **Well - i am still wondering if there is any better way to perform the same.**

ALSO - I have also used a **STATIC member** in the class which i am **COMPELLED** to use since i want to *share the Users logged in session between the classes instantiated by the factory*.

Here is the script just incase it helps someone someday or better it.

```
public class FactoryMethod {
    @Factory(dataProvider="dataSuite")
    public Object[] createInstances(int id, String TestSuite) {
        return new Object[] {new FactoryMethodClass(id, TestSuite)};
    }

    @DataProvider(name="dataSuite")
    public static Object[][] dataSuite() {
        Object[][] dataArray = {{1, "TEST SUITE 1"},{2, "TEST SUITE 2"}};
        return dataArray;
    }
}

public class FactoryMethodClass {
    private static int SHAREDcounter = 1000;
    private int id = 100;
    private String TestSuite = "";

    public FactoryMethodClass(){}

    public FactoryMethodClass(int id, String TestSuite) {this.id = id; this.TestSuite = TestSuite;}

    @DataProvider(name="dataRecords")
    public static Object[][] dataPro() {
        Object[][] dataArray = {{1, "TEST RECORD 1"}, {2, "TEST RECORD 2"}, {3, "TEST RECORD 3"}};
        return dataArray;
    }

    @Test (dataProvider="dataRecords")
    public void firstDataPro(int id, String TestRecord) {
        System.out.println("Running Test Record " + TestRecord  + " of Test Suite " + TestSuite + " with Value = " + SHAREDcounter++);
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```